C# WPF- MenuItem on MouseOver style does not work
I want the Menu Control's Background to be Grayish on Mouse Hover and same for the Sub Menu items.

But with my below code,on hover the color does not change.
<Menu Grid.Column="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="62" Height="20" Background="#FFFFFF" Foreground="#005F87">
    <MenuItem>
        <MenuItem.Header>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="Auto">
                <Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="Images/image1.png"/>
                <TextBlock Text=" Style" Height="16" Width="40" Foreground="#005F87" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontWeight="DemiBold" />
            </StackPanel>
        </MenuItem.Header>

        <MenuItem Header="Default" IsCheckable="True" Background="#FFFFFF" Foreground="#005F87" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Segoe UI" Click="MenuDefault_Click"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Channel" IsCheckable="True" Background="#FFFFFF" Foreground="#005F87" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Segoe UI" Click="MenuChannel_Click"/>
        <MenuItem.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="2"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkGray"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </MenuItem.Resources>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>


Can anybody please tell me what am I missing?
Thank you in advance!

You have to create your own custom Controltemplate,you can easily by editing Menu & MenuItem from Xaml then select edit a copy then add those Triggers there
